# Actions on Google - CLI (gactions) comment not found

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google

This questions maybe already asked but that is not solve my issue.

I'm trying to deploy my gactions script in `google cloud function`. So for that I have installed the [gactions CLI](https://developers.google.com/assistant/df-asdk/actions-sdk/gactions-cli) in `Ubuntu 20.04` machine, but I'm having some problems.

The mentioned [gactions CLI](https://developers.google.com/assistant/df-asdk/actions-sdk/gactions-cli) comments not working in terminal, it's shows `[ERROR] unknown command "test" for "gactions"` error message.

**Eg:** `gactions test --action_package action.json --project PROJECT_ID`

[image]

Am using `gactions version 3.2.0`. Please suggest me how to use those comments in terminal.

> I have tried with `sudo gactions test --action_package action.json --project PROJECT_ID` that also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error [ERROR] unknown command "test" for "gactions" describes that the test command is not validating by the gactions CLI.

Might be due to below reasons, can you you have a check on this :

- As per this [official doc](https://developers.google.com/assistant/df-asdk/actions-sdk/gactions-cli#supported-arguments) , you are trying to execute the text command
  but make sure the [action package](https://developers.google.com/assistant/df-asdk/reference/action-package/rest/Shared.Types/ActionPackage) name given by you is correct.
- Can you try any other arguments mentioned in the [gactions supported
  arguments doc](https://developers.google.com/assistant/df-asdk/actions-sdk/gactions-cli#supported-arguments) and have a try whether those are validating or not.
- Enable the Actions API in the Google Cloud console by following the
  instructions in [Enable and disable APIs](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158841). This allows gactions to
  interact with your project.
- Make sure you have installed the gactions CLI correctly by running
  the command '[gactions version](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actionssdk/gactions/guide#listing_versions)' to check the version number. If the
  version number matches the version you installed, then the CLI is
  probably installed correctly. If not reinstall the CLI using this
  [gactions overview](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actionssdk/gactions)

Comment: Hi @Hemanth Kumar thanks for the answer. I checked all the points. All the points are correct. But still test commend not working

Comment: @RameshS : Can you share the screenshot post executing the other arguments mentioned in this [gactions supported arguments doc](https://developers.google.com/assistant/df-asdk/actions-sdk/gactions-cli#supported-arguments)

Comment: I have uploaded the images please check https://ibb.co/cDKV3C5 and 
https://ibb.co/xmPcCm4

Comment: @RameshS : The only solution now is to reinstall the CLI again using this [gactions installing doc](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actionssdk/gactions#install_the_gactions_command-line_tool)

Comment: can you please provide me the link for gactions version 2.2.3 for Ubuntu

Comment: I found the issue that is version mismatch

Comment: Can you update the same in my answer and accept it.

Comment: how can I install gactions version 2.2.3

Comment: I got [2.2.2v](https://dl.google.com/gactions/updates/bin/linux/arm/gactions) and will share it with you if i get 2.2.3

Comment: Hi  while using this commend login is not happens `./gactions --verbose  test --action_package action.json --project PROJECT-ID` am getting this error `Access blocked: Assistant CLI’s request is invalid`

Comment: Raise a new question as per [stack guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275908/more-than-one-question-per-post/275909#275909). So, that it could be helpful for community members to follow.

Comment: Hi please check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75541029/gactions-access-blocked-assistant-cli-s-request-is-invalid